# Passing a paramater using HyperlinkField inside a GridView and opening a popup

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, gridview, popup

Im having an issue passing a parameter using HyperLinkField inside a Gridview while opening a popup. I need to pass 2 paramaters in the URL, how can I let it know about it?

This is what I currently have:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField Text="Details" NavigateURL="javascript:var w =window.open('ProviderDetailPop.aspx','details','width=520,height=560,left=450,top=150,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,status=yes,toolbar=no')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct your NavigateURL value using String.Format and pass your parameters.  A rough example is below

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEmployee" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Employee") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/yourPage.aspx?p={0}", Eval("ID")) %>' />
```